# For Loop with data Binding

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I am trying to databind position 0 as "" in a number of dropdownlists, my code below:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is DropDownList Then
        ctrl.DataBind()
        ctrl.items.insert(0, "")
    End If

Next
```

I get error: Error  BC30456 'items' is not a member of 'Control'

I am a bit at a loss... Please help!

Thanks Tim, what would the code then be to add the "" to the dropboxes..

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the `Control` to `DropDownList`,otherwise you cant use properties or methods of the child-class  `DropDownList` but only of `Control`.

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is DropDownList Then  '          <--- Type-Check
        Dim ddl = DirectCast(ctrl, DropDownList)  ' <--- Cast
        ddl.DataBind()
        ddl.items.insert(0, "")
    End If
Next
```

Here's another way using `Enumerable.OfType` (add `Imports System.Linq` at the top of the file):

```
For Each ddl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of DropDownList)()
    ddl.DataBind()
    ddl.items.insert(0, "")
Next
```

---

[`Control.Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) does not return controls recursively, so not nested child controls. Maybe your `DropDownList` is in another container control like a `GridView`, then you wont find it in this way. In this case the correct way would be to handle the `RowDataBound`-event and use `GridViewRow.FindControl("drpSite")` to get the reference. If you can't do that or you want to use a recursive way to find all `DropDownLists` you can use this extension method:

```
Public Module Extensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function OfTypeRecursive(Of T As Control)(ByVal root As Control) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim allControls = New List(Of T)
        Dim queue = New Queue(Of Control)
        queue.Enqueue(root)
        While queue.Count > 0
            Dim c As Control = queue.Dequeue()
            For Each child As Control In c.Controls
                queue.Enqueue(child)
                If TypeOf child Is T Then allControls.Add(DirectCast(child, T))
            Next
        End While
        Return allControls
    End Function
End Module
```

Now it's simple:

```
Dim allDdls As IEnumerable(Of DropDownList) = Me.OfTypeRecursive(Of DropDownList)()
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I tried these options as given, but no success I do not get an error it just doesn't do anything I inserted the code under the page load  sub...

Comment: @MardusDavel: then there is no `DropDownList` on top of the page. Maybe it is in a `GridView` or another container control. `Control.Controls` is not looking into sub-controls, so there is no recursive search involved. You should show us the relevant part of your aspx.

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="drpSite" runat="server" style="height: 20px; top: 164px; left: 702px; position: absolute; width: 163px">
        </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: @MardusDavel: always edit your question if you add details. But with _relevant_ part i meant that you should show where this dropdownlist is declared, we also need to see the surrounding controls.

Answer (score 0):

DataBind() is not necessary if the dropDownList is already bounded. you can insert values to required index as like the following code, You are getting the error because the Sysetem.web.UI.Controls doesn't have a items. so you can achieve this by `casting the ctrl as a DropDownList`

```
   For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is DropDownList Then
            Dim tempDropDown As DropDownList = DirectCast(ctrl, DropDownList)
            tempDropDown.Items.Insert(0, "")
        End If
    Next
```